# How to stop victory axis behave differently when there are 0 values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, victory-charts

If you go to the first example demonstration [here](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-bar), with code:

```
<VictoryChart
  theme={VictoryTheme.material}
  domainPadding={10}
>
  <VictoryBar
    style={{ data: { fill: "#c43a31" } }}
    data={sampleData}
  />
</VictoryChart>
```

you see that the bars are looking good, aligned nicely:

[image]

But once you change the code like this (adding a data point with a 0 x value):

```
<VictoryChart
  theme={VictoryTheme.material}
  domainPadding={10}
>
  <VictoryBar
    style={{ data: { fill: "#c43a31" } }}
    data={[{x: 0, y: 2}, ...sampleData]}
  />
</VictoryChart>
```

You see that the new bar is going weird. I sort of get it why it's like this. If negative values would be present, then they would be shown to the left from the y axis. But I find it very frustrating that I couldn't find a way to turn this off, and handle 0, or even negative values like positive ones, and just show the axis on the left always.

I'm using custom `VictoryAxis`, and tried different `domainPadding`s, played with `singleQuadrantDomainPadding`, but nothing worked.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use set `offsetX` and set `tickValues` to deal with the `x=0` problem.

Here's the code:

```
<VictoryChart
  theme={VictoryTheme.material}
  domainPadding={10}
>
  <VictoryBar
    style={{ data: { fill: "#c43a31", padding: 15 } }}
    data={[{x:0, y:2}, ...sampleData]}
  />
  <VictoryAxis tickValues={[-0.25, 0,1,2,3,4,5]} tickFormat={t => t>=0 ? t: ''} />
  <VictoryAxis offsetX={60}  crossAxis dependentAxis/>
</VictoryChart>
```

And the effect:

[image]